# Creating mapfile for MapServer in QGIS?

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

How can I create mapfile (.map) for MapServer 7.0 in QGIS 2.18 or 3.0?

Or are there any tools which are part of the core MapServer distribution?

And what is the best visual tool for create mapfile now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapfile exporter plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rt_mapserver_exporter/ is deprecated so unfortunately you can't create mapfiles with QGIS. It might be possible if you can install some very old QGIS version, like 2.6 or less but even then the plugin does not make mapfiles which work with MapServer versions 7.x without some manual fixes.

Other tools that you can try are MapManager the http://gisinternals.com/mapmanager.html (if you are on Windows) and ScribeUI http://scribeui.org/. MapManager should work but some gis.stackexchange user asked recently about a problem with installing it on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, thanks your answered. I try this tools, and I think the mapserver is best for the experienced users, and mapserver should be develop a virsual tool for its part of the core distribution.

Comment: Yes, thanks your answered. I try this tools, and I think the mapserver is best for the experienced users, and mapserver should be develop a virsual tool for its part of the core distribution.